# Can I install plugin on Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

How to install elasticsearch-river-mongodb plugin to Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From [Amazon ES limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html)

> Custom plugins    The service does not support custom plugins. However,
>   the service does support several standard plugins, including Kibana,
>   ICU, and Kuromoji.

There are few (necessary) plugins that are installed by deafult but you cannot install your own

Comment: Supported plugins: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-plugins.html