# Install delete-by-query plugin in AWS ES service

Tags: amazon-elasticsearch

How do I install delete-by-query plugin in AWS ES service? I'm using Elasticsearch (version 2.3). I am not sure whether it is even possible to install plugin in AWS ES service (assume preloaded and cannot be customized).

My current research indicates that [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403945/can-i-install-plugin-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service?rq=1) - can someone confirm?

Comment: Looks like not possible -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403945/can-i-install-plugin-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service?rq=1. Can someone please confirm?

Comment: I don't know this technology, but your question is extremely brief and might be close-voted just on that basis. Is there any supporting information you can add?

Comment: @halfer I just want to know whether delete-by-query plugin can be installed in AWS ES service. Since delete-by-plugin is not part of the Elasticsearch (version 2.3) package, I need community help to understand how people delete specific data in ES given the case. So far from my search I do not think AWS ES allows user to install plugin.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late response, but if someone is looking for the answer - the plugin is supported in AWS Elasticsearch since version 5.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_5_1