# aws opensearch custom plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

i am new to aws opensearch,
is it possible to write custom plugin as we use to do for opeansearch
sample : https://logz.io/blog/opensearch-plugins/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, AWS managed Opensearch service does not allow to install additional plugins.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403945/can-i-install-plugin-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service